# How can I upgrade the deprecated UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass method to something iOS 16 compatible?

Tags: ios, swift, url, uti, uttype

I'm trying to convert this deprecated bit of code into its iOS 16 compatible form:

```
extension URL {
    public static func pathExtensionForUTI(_ uti: String) -> String? {
        return UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass(uti as CFString, kUTTagClassFilenameExtension)?.takeRetainedValue() as String?
    }
}
```

This is a static method on URL that returns an optional path extension string for the UTI, which is passed into the method from elsewhere.

I thought the solution would be something like this, using preferredFilenameExtension to get the path extension:

```
    public static func pathExtensionForUTI(_ uti: String) -> String? {
        return UTType(filenameExtension: uti)?.preferredFilenameExtension
    }
```

However, this doesn't work as expected and I am pretty sure that it is returning a nil value since the operation cancels itself. I'm unable to trigger a breakpoint to verify this since the method is called from outside the app (e.g., sharing a photo from the Photos app).

I've also tried:

```
    public func pathExtensionForUTI(_ uti: String) -> String? {
        return UTType(filenameExtension: self.pathExtension)?.preferredFilenameExtension
    }
```

But this requires turning the static method into an instance method and creating several URL objects. It also doesn't take into account the passed-in uti.

Thanks in advance for any insight you can provide!

Comment: What were you trying to achieve with the original code? Give an example of input and expected output please.

Answer (score 1):

Your code returns the preferred path extension for a string identifier like `public.jpeg`. This is pretty easy with `UTType`, you have to use the [`init` method taking an identifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers/uttype/3551509-init)

```
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

func pathExtensionForUTI(_ identifier: String) -> String? {
    UTType(identifier)?.preferredFilenameExtension
}

pathExtensionForUTI("public.jpeg")
```

I would put the code into an extension of `UTType` rather than `URL`